# How do you get a different name to pop up when you click the button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new working on python and this is my first "big" project. This is what I have worked on for the day. I am trying to work on this project that randomly generates a name when you click on a category and press the generate button. It randomly generates one name but when I press the generate button again it doesn't display another name. That's what I'm trying to figure out. Also if anyone doesn't mind, how can I check a box and generate a name on that category.

Thank you very much

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, StringVar, filedialog, Text
import os
import random
from tkinter import font

randomfirst = ("Hunter", "Rage", "Ash", "Money", "Ace", "Charles", "Ajax", "Rocket", "Harden",
"Blaze", "Rich", "Ghost", "Joker", "Queen", "Azure", "Zeus", "Apollo", "Hephaistos", "Aqua",
"Rain", "Apex", "Flame", "Cronos", "Kim", "Adras", "Achilles", "Alena", "Hades",
"Ares", "Athena", "Alistair", "Alyx")
Random1 = random.choice(randomfirst)

randomlast = ("Parker", "Nereus", "Reaper", "Bacchus", "Aino", "Tara", "Eris", "Iuno", "Devaraja", "Hector"
"Aditi", "Mabon", "Astraia", "Deimos", "Demeos", "Demon", "Lucifer", "Angel", "Kerberos", "Cerberus", "Zinon",
"Lycus", "Lamia", "Thanatos", "Leucippus", "Thaleia")
Random2 = random.choice(randomlast)

Medievalname = ("Zemislav", "Wolf", "Titian", "Teague", "Savage", "Salvador", "Rogue", "Richard", "Radax", "Pascal",
"Osmund", "Novel", "Milo", "Maurin", "Lucan", "Justus", "Jerome", "Hawk",
"Gregory", "Finnian", "Emil", "Drew", "Crispin", "Bjorn", "Alan")
Medieval = random.choice(Medievalname)

GreekMythname= ("Acestes", "Achilles", "Acis", "Acontius", "Actaeon",
"Admetus", "Adonis", "Aecus", "Aedon", "Aeolus", "Baucis",
"Bellerophon", "Bendis", "Biton", "Boreas", "Briareus", "Busiris",
"Britomaris", "Caberiri")
GreekMyth = random.choice(GreekMythname)

Japanesename = ("Fuji", "Homura", "Kaito", "Mizu", "Shimizu", "Asahi",
"Sora", "Riku", "Fujin", "Izanagi", "Kuebiko", "Raiden", "Raijin",
"Ryujin", "Kojin", "Suijin", "Tenjin", "Tsukiyomi", "Takemikazuchi",
"Aoki", "Endo", "Inoue", "Ito")
Japanese = random.choice(Japanesename)



root = tk.Tk()

def onClick():
    labelRandomname = tk.Label(framedisplay, text=(GreekMyth), font= ("Broadway", 36), bg="#d3d3d3")
    labelRandomname.
    labelRandomname.pack()
    labelRandomname.place(relx= 0.35, rely= 0.35)



i= StringVar()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width= 800, bg="#17517e")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg= "white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.97, relheight=0.97, relx= 0.015, rely= 0.015)

framedisplay = tk.Frame(root, bg= "#d3d3d3")
framedisplay.place(relwidth= 0.75, relheight= 0.35, relx= 0.125, rely= 0.575)

labelwelcome = tk.Label(frame, text=" Random Name Generator! ", width= 25, height= 1,
                        font= ("Berlin Sans FB", 24), fg= "red", bg= "white")
labelwelcome.pack()

labelYourname = tk.Label(framedisplay, text= "Your name is: ", font= ("Berlin Sans FB", 20), bg= "#d3d3d3")
labelYourname.pack()

labelCategory = tk.Label(frame, text= "Select your name category",
                        font= ("Arial", 14))
labelCategory.pack()
labelCategory.place(relx= 0.350, rely= 0.105)

medievalCheck = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text= "Medieval", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= i, onvalue="checked", offvalue="unchecked")
medievalCheck.deselect()
medievalCheck.pack()
medievalCheck.place(relx= 0.20, rely= 0.160)

greekmythCheck = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text= "Greek Mythology", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= i, onvalue="checked", offvalue="unchecked")
greekmythCheck.deselect()
greekmythCheck.pack()
greekmythCheck.place(relx= 0.40, rely= 0.160)

japaneseCheck = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text= "Japanese", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= i, onvalue="checked", offvalue="unchecked")
japaneseCheck.deselect()
japaneseCheck.pack()
japaneseCheck.place(relx= 0.67, rely= 0.160)

romanCheck = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text= "Roman", font= ("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= i, onvalue="checked", offvalue="unchecked")
romanCheck.deselect()
romanCheck.pack()
romanCheck.place(relx= 0.20, rely= 0.25)

fantasyCheck = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text="Fantasy", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= i, onvalue="checked", offvalue="unchecked")
fantasyCheck.deselect()
fantasyCheck.pack()
fantasyCheck.place(relx= 0.40, rely= 0.25)

russianCheck = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text="Russian", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= i, onvalue="checked", offvalue="unchecked")
russianCheck.deselect()
russianCheck.pack()
russianCheck.place(relx= 0.67, rely= 0.25)


generateButton = tk.Button(frame, text= "Generate!", padx=40, pady= 25, fg= "grey", bg= "black", foreground= "White",
                           font=("Bauhaus 93", 20), command= onClick)
generateButton.pack()
generateButton.place(relx= 0.36, rely= 0.40)

    


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the issue is that You set those words once when running the code and never change them, You have to choose again from the list, for example `Random1 = random.choice(randomfirst)` will run only once and then won't change unless you change it somewhere in Your code for example call the same line in some function (using `global` but...)

Comment: I was looking at the easiest way to sort out your checkboxes, no time today though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name choices are more naturally organized as `Radiobutton` widgets.

```py
nameType = StringVar()
nameType.set("Medieval")

medievalCheck = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text= "Medieval", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12),variable= nameType, value="Medieval" )
medievalCheck.place(relx= 0.20, rely= 0.160)

greekmythCheck = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text= "Greek Mythology", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12), variable= nameType, value="Greek Mythology")
greekmythCheck.place(relx= 0.40, rely= 0.160)
```

and so on for the other types.

Then for a changing display, your best bet is to have another `StringVar` in the `Label`:

```py
displayName = StringVar()
displayName.set("")
labelRandomname = tk.Label(framedisplay, textvariable=displayName, font= ("Broadway", 36), bg="#d3d3d3")
labelRandomname.place(relx= 0.1, rely= 0.35)
```

and finally you need both a dictionary to look up the radio button state, and a random pick within the event responder

```py
Russianname = ("Boris","Ivan","Anna","Katya")

NameOpts = {"Medieval":Medievalname, "Greek Mythology":GreekMythname, "Japanese":Japanesename,
            "Roman":randomlast, "Fantasy":randomfirst, "Russian":Russianname}

def onClick():
    cat = nameType.get()
    displayName.set(random.choice(NameOpts[cat]))
```

(I added a few Russian names to cover this option)